# What is the term for a transitive antisymmetric relation?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, order-theory

What is the term for a transitive antisymmetric relation?  I mean, a relation $\prec$ that satisfies

1. if $a\prec b$ and $b\prec c$, then $a\prec c$,
2. if $a\prec b$ and $b\prec a$, then $a = b$.

What is its place in Order Theory?

For example, the following relation $\prec$ on subsets of a topological space is transitive and antisymmetric, but generally is neither a partial order nor a strict partial order:

> Let $X\prec Y$ mean that there is an open set $U$ such that $X\subset U\subset Y$.

(By $A\subset B$ I mean that $A$ is a subset of $B$.  In particular, $A\subset A$ for all $A$.)

P.S.  I thought of this relation on subsets of a topological space because if I define the analogues of such order-theoretic notions as *supremum*, *directed set*, and [*compact element*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_element), then compact subsets of a topological space will be exactly the compact elements of this relation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders

Comment: That would be a preorder, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder

Comment: @Jason, according to your link, a preorder is reflexive.

Comment: @Jason: And a pre-order is a partial order without the antisymmetry, so this is certainly not the relevant term.

Comment: Alexey, Asaf Karagila, you are both correct. I misread.